# Как закрыть Dialog при клике на кнопку в Activity

Tags: android

Возникла проблема. Есть toolbar и на нем кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку открывается полноэкранный Dialog с маргином на верхний тулбар. То есть, тулбар виден. На нем есть кнопка закрытия.
Вопрос. Как обработать клик на эту кнопку и закрыть Dialog?

Comment: Когда вызывается диалог, активность ставится на паузу и взаимодействовать с ней "вручную" нельзя. Почему бы вам не обрабатывать закрытие в самом диалоге?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сможете взаимодействовать с активити, пока открыт диалог. Однако вы можете добавить кнопку закрытия диалога в нем самом.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

AlertDialog.Builder ad;
Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = MainActivity.this; 
    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    ad.setTitle("Удаление сообщения" );  // заголовок
    ad.setMessage("Вы действительно хотите его удалить? "); // сообщение
    ad.setPositiveButton("Да" , new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
            //обрабатывает нажатие кнопки 'Да' 
        }
    });
    ad.setNegativeButton("Нет", new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
           //обрабатывает нажатие кнопки 'Нет' 
        }
    });
```

Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее вы можете прочитать [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/alertdialog.php)